# Break Long Strings Of Text That Don't Contain A Space

Tags: php

How can I put spaces to a long string that does not have spaces

```
Example : 5Bedroom.Apartment,in.NewYork>City
```

I want to put spaces after any dot and comma. Only if no space after dot and comma. If already have space, just ignore

Comment: Take a look at using regular expressions.  You would want to use look arounds.

Answer (score 0):

Such regex `~(?<=[,.])(?=\S)~` matches position after comma or dot before not space

```
$str = preg_replace( ~(?<=[,.])(?=\S)~, " ", $str);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/953052)

Answer (score 0):

**you should replace the charector which u want**

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<!\d),|,(?!\d{3})/', ', ', $str);
```